# database project doesn't drop indexes/triggers before create them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, publish, database-project

I have table that I can't control via db project, but I need index and trigger on it. That means I dont use right mouse on db proj -> add -> table. I use simple script (right mouse on db proj -> add -> script) where I have next code

```
    GO 
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_om_event_venue_id] ON [dbo].[event]([venue_id] ASC)
```

when I generate publish script it always inserts code above into publish script. But it shouldn't in cases when same index exists.
In the result I get an error:

> (1077,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1913, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_om_event_venue_id' already exists on table 'dbo.event'.

What should I do to forse script generator to compare code above with existing database schema?

PS

I have several more such expressions in file, for examle:

```
    GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_om_ticket_voided_invoice_ticket_group_id] ON [dbo].[ticket_voided_invoice]([ticket_group_id] ASC)
```

But they are processed as they should - they are not added into publish script if database already has it

Comment: Most likely you need to pull that base DB in as a DB Reference before adding the script. Indexes are part of the "CREATE TABLE" script by default.  Alternatively, you could use an IF NOT EXISTS ... CREATE INDEX in a post-deploy script.  However, I think you need the actual DB schema in your project to do a schema compare.

Comment: @PeterSchott We disabled publishing tables without our project prefixes, we publish only 'om_' tables and my problem exactly relayed to non 'om_' table. I have 1 file where i have several CREATE INDEX scripts for one table, but only one I described is not checked by Contributor